# How to Get 4 Squre Point From Center latitude & longitude

Tags: php

can you please any one help me for find a square point using below latitude & longitude ?

```
$Latitude = 23.203984;
$Longitude = 72.635021;
```

I would like to create a square geofence using this point

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show some code!

Comment: Please go read [ask], and explain what the actual problem is.

Comment: No,  Want to some logic so i can implement

Comment: There are several php libraries and solutions in the first page of a simple google search. with no further information we can't help you

Answer (score 1):

You have to count use next formula

```
$lat="";
$lon="";
$squareSide = $length /2; // radians
$p1 = $lat-$squareSide;
$p2 = $lon-$squareSide;
$p3 = $lat+$squareSide;
$p4 = $lon+$squareSide;
```

$p1...$p4 - will be corners of the square